# How can I stream a ZIP archive with just one file in it?

Tags: stream, zip

Imagine this situation: I have a ZIP archive with exactly one entry. I know the name of the entry in advance.

How can I expand this single entry without having to read the whole ZIP archive first?

Details: The TOC of a ZIP archive is appended to the end of the ZIP archive. So usually, you can't start reading entries before you have read the whole archive. Other archivers like `tar` or `gzip` give me the header first and then the entry data.

In my case, the archive is only a single file and I know the file name (`content.xml`, no path).

Comment: Why isn't it just gzip than? It would have been more appropriate.

Comment: The server of the file is not under my control.

Answer (score 0):

While it's not really guaranteed to work by the specification, in your case it should work to just search for the start of first entry. You can decompress it and than verify you actually got the data you wanted when you get to the end and decompress the directory.

I don't know whether any library supports this and given it's not officially supported would expect that not. So you'd have to take apart some reader (e.g. the minizip bundled in zlib should be reasonably simple) and implement this yourself.